# Magento redirect to homepage after add product to compare

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Is there a way to understand why is redirecting to homepage after a product is added to compare ?, i have disabled all extensions and it is still redirecting to homepage.

The version used is 1.8.0 .

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

is called in addAction of Compare-Controller.

protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
    {

```
    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see $defaultUrl is empty when _redirectReferer is called. $refererUrl is empty too. Thus the redirect to Mage::getBaseUrl().

When you take a look at

```
protected function _getRefererUrl()
{
    $refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = $url;
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
    }

    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($refererUrl);

    if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }
    return $refererUrl;
}
```

you see that you can add a param to your compare/add call where you hand over a redirect url, via self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL. The const value behind this is "referer_url", so just add a param referer_url to the request, with whatever internal location you want to redirect afterwards. Or you simply set $defaultUrl variable.

Comment: What i want is to stay in the same page, as the normal, but i cannot understand why on Windows with Zend server is ok, and on centos server is going to homepage. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

magento added product to compare contoller  `Mage>controlers>Catalog>Product>CompareController.php` 
_redirectReferer();
This which is give you last visited  page`,thought_redirectReferer() gives redirection url to home page`...

If you specify in the url a parameter uenc it will consider that as the referrer.

if you want to redirect to product then add this code to

then add code $this->_redirectUrl($product->getProductUrl()); in addAction()

```
 if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The product %s has been added to comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
                );
                Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
        $this->_redirectUrl($product->getProductUrl());
            }
```

Comment: Well i found the issue, is Varnish Cache working on front with port 80 and Nginx with port 8080, so Magento is trying to get the URL www.website.com:8080/url.html but the url is not valid and from here it redirects to home page

Comment: good,please mention this thing on question that you have varnish cache

Comment: i know this thread is a bit old, but how could did you fix that Dario?